# LR(1) - How to compute Lookaheads

Tags: parsing, context-free-grammar, lr1

I have trouble understanding how to compute the lookaheads.

Lets say that I have this extend grammar:

```
S'-> S
S -> L=R | R
L -> *R | i
R -> L
```

I wrote the State 0 so:

```
S'-> .S, {$}
S -> .L=R, {$}
S -> .R, {$}
L -> .*R, {=,$}
L -> .i, {=,$}
R -> .L {=,$}
```

Using many parsing emulator i see that all calculators says:

```
R -> .L {$}
```

Why? Can't the R be followed by a "="?

Comment: http://cs.stackexchange.com/ is a better place to ask this.

Comment: do i repost this there or what?

Comment: Yes. There you'll have more chance of your question being answered.